# jbgallery vs supersized js vs flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, slideshow, image-gallery

I have been asked to create a website where the homepage consists of a fading image slideshow and a navigation bar at the bottom of the page. The client wants the image to cover the entire screen with the exception of this nav bar with a pause/play button at the top right of the screen.

I have built this using the supersized jquery function and made a few tweaks, but there seems to be performance issues with the fading effect (its very static and transitions dont appear to flow very smoothly).

Before I get stuck into the remainder of the site, I want some advice from the seasoned experts out there on using this function, or the jbgallery jquery function I have recently come across. Alternatively what is the general consensus on building the whole site in flash.

I haved used flash sparingly before due to CMS issues (which I have now worked around) and ipad display problems etc so would need to do a bit of learning to go down this route but am more than happy to adopt the approach if people really think it is worthwhile. My experience to date has consisted of including swf animations and components within php pages populated via mysql using xml files.

Looking forward to any and all advice (not simply for this project but future ones aswell!).

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually trying to work out the exact same problem right now. I don't have a perfect/easy solution yet, but here's something that might work:
http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/

It's a jQuery plugin that takes your standard `animate()` calls (and a few others) and uses CSS3 transforms when possible. This will theoretically improve the frame rate of transitions since CSS3 effects perform better in modern browsers. I have smaller demos working, but am having trouble getting a lower frame rate for full-browser images.

Comment: just read the link you provided - very interesting. Would you mind showing me one of your smaller demos so I can see how you have adopted the plugin? No worries if not, I hate putting things out there that arent the finished article!

Comment: Can't share yet, but I'll definitely put together a blog post if I can get it to work smoothly. There are lots of CSS3 slideshow examples and lots of full-browser slideshow examples, but I've yet to find one that  marries the two.